# What's better, delegates or singletons to pass data between view controllers- Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, singleton, protocols

I have been practicing with different methods to pass data between view controllers and so far I have tried delegates and singletons. After trying these two patterns I started wondering if one is better than the other or it is simply a metter of taste. In my opinion the singleton pattern seems to be very straight forward and simpler, it also seems to conform to the MVC since it completly separates the model from the controllers.

1- Is one pattern better than the other?
2- What method do you use?
3- Why do you prefer one over than the other?

Sorry if my question doesnt make too much sense but I want to hear from the pros and try to use what makes more sense.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: In general, a singleton should be a last resort.

Comment: Create a Data Model that can be used by the classes.

Comment: use NSNotificationCenter rather than singletons.

Comment: BLOCKS. I prefer blocks to pass data between controllers.

Comment: `@Zaph - Create a Data Model that can be used by the classes. `  Do you know of any documentation/tutorial where I can read more about this method?

Answer (score 1):

Accourding to example apps from Apple, delegates more preferable way. They use less memory and be able to make you connection between objects loosely coupled. Suppose you have View Controllers (A and B) and singleton Object S (with was initialised sometimes before, maybe in AppDelegate.h). For example, B need to download some data(D) and return to A. In case of singleton it will store D even if don't need it in A.

Comment: I got downvoted plenty of times on two instances when I suggested this as a possible solution to passing data between view controllers! You're lucky you haven't received a downvote yet! I like this of passing data between my view controllers but have had to do things differently since the downvotes lol

Comment: Can you justify "they use less memory"? And maybe expand on loose coupling?

Comment: I pass data in prepareForSegue or it's already stored in core data or user defaults.  sometimes nsnotifcation passes data.  Sometimes I use singletons, but try to avoid it as much as possible as singletons have a bad habit of growing and growing over time.

Comment: Why is that a bad idea? If I may know..